# Formula Field for visual Indicator field is not working

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities

IF(( Active__c = TRUE),
Image(https://cloudanalogy-d8-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com/resource/1659944473000/Green?,GREEN,10,10),
Image(https://cloudanalogy-d8-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com/resource/1659944516000/Red?,RED,10,10))

This is the formula I used to create a visual Indicator Field to Associate the Active Employee with a Green Dot in front of their Names.
And it's Showing me the following error.

Error: Syntax error. Found '/'
Need Help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes in image name

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000327122&type=1